# How to add custom font to JFreeChart with CP1250 encoding

Tags: java, itext, jfreechart

I have a problem to set encoding of JFreeChart chart title font. I created pdf and added chart to it. I created custom font using itext library and set encoding to CP1250. The special characters shows in pdf, I mapped this font to java.awt.Font but the same letters doesnt show on chart title. Is there any other way to achieve this goal?
[image]

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(null,"Rok","Liczba wszystkich emisji", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, true);
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.CACHED);
        Font font = new Font(baseFont, 9);
        document.add(new Paragraph("śćżźółąę abcdefhgijklmnop", font));
        DefaultFontMapper defaultFontMapper = new DefaultFontMapper();
        java.awt.Font titleFont = defaultFontMapper.pdfToAwt(baseFont,20);
        StandardChartTheme chartTheme = new StandardChartTheme("theme");
        chartTheme.setRegularFont(titleFont);
        ChartFactory.setChartTheme(chartTheme);
        chart.setTitle(new TextTitle("śćżźółąę abcdefhgijklmnop"));
        chart.getTitle().setFont(titleFont);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. But maybe you need to set your font also for the ExtraLarge and Large variants of the theme. Maybe try something like this:

```
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(null,"Rok","Liczba wszystkich emisji", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, true);
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.CACHED);
    Font font = new Font(baseFont, 9);
    document.add(new Paragraph("śćżźółąę abcdefhgijklmnop", font));
    DefaultFontMapper defaultFontMapper = new DefaultFontMapper();
    java.awt.Font titleFont = defaultFontMapper.pdfToAwt(baseFont,20);
    StandardChartTheme chartTheme = new StandardChartTheme("theme");
    chartTheme.setExtraLargeFont(font.deriveFont(24f));
    chartTheme.setLargeFont(font.deriveFont(16f));
    chartTheme.setRegularFont(font.deriveFont(12f));
    chartTheme.setSmallFont(font.deriveFont(10f));
    ChartFactory.setChartTheme(chartTheme);
    ChartFactory.setChartTheme(chartTheme);
    chart.setTitle(new TextTitle("śćżźółąę abcdefhgijklmnop"));
    chart.getTitle().setFont(titleFont);
```

Comment: Instead of spending lot of hours, it is better to use pdf font by drawing a string in CP1250 encoding and set its position to charts title position